# get id by value in hierarcial data with js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, hierarchy, hierarchical-data

I have hierarcial data as tree array:

```
var myData = [
    {
      id: 0,
      title:"Item 1"
    }, {
      id: 1,
      title:"Item 2",
      subs: [
        {
          id: 10,
          title:"Item 2-1",
          subs: [
        {
          id: 100,
          title:"Item 2-2-1"
        }, {
          id: 110,
          title:"Item 2-2-2"
        }, {
          id: 120,
          title:"Item 2-2-3"
        }
      ]
        }, {
          id: 11,
          title:"Item 2-2"
        }, {
          id: 12,
          title:"Item 2-3"
        }
      ]
    }, {
      id: 2,
      title:"Item 3"
    },
    // more data here
];
```

I need to get id by title in this array. I try to use this function:

```
console.log(myData.findIndex(item=>item.title==="Item 3"))
```

But it works bad for "Item 2-2". How should I solve this problem?

Comment: Do subitems possibly have indefinite subitems?

Comment: yes,they are. subitems possibly have indefinite subitems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made this simple `findId` method in order to find the title and returns the `id` or `undefined` as result made for your data array structure.

> `findId(title, list)` function.
> Its purpose is to iterate the list received in the second parameter, look for the title in each element and if there is a match it returns the id, otherwise it checks if there are `subs` in the element and in that case it is called recursively the `findId` function using the subs of the element as a list. If an element is found, its id is returned, otherwise the iteration continues.

**This will work fine, assuming each title is unique in the array.**
***Otherwise only the first will be found.***

*Take a look at the following*

```js
function findId(title, list) {
  for (const _item of list) {
    if (_item.title === title) {
      // Return some top-level id
      return _item.id;
      
    // If the item is not the one, check if it has subs
    } else if (_item?.subs) { 
    
      // Use _item.subs as a list, calling the function recursively
      const subId = findId(title, _item.subs);
      
      // Return some nested subId if found
      if (subId !== undefined) return subId;
    }
  }
  // Return undefined if not found
  return undefined;
}


var myData = [
{
    id: 0,
    title: "Item 1"
  }, 
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Item 2",
    subs: [
    {
      id: 10,
      title: "Item 2-1",
      subs: [
      {
        id: 100,
        title: "Item 2-2-1"
      }, {
        id: 110,
        title: "Item 2-2-2"
      }, {
        id: 120,
        title: "Item 2-2-3"
      }]
    }, {
      id: 11,
      title: "Item 2-2"
    }, {
      id: 12,
      title: "Item 2-3"
    }]
  }, 
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Item 3"
  },
  // more data here
];

console.log("Id: ", findId("Item 2", myData));
console.log("Id: ", findId("Item 2-1", myData));
console.log("Id: ", findId("Item 2-2-2", myData));
console.log("Id: ", findId("Wrong Title", myData));
```

```html
console.log("Id: ", findId("Item 2", myData));<br/>
console.log("Id: ", findId("Item 2-1", myData));<br/>
console.log("Id: ", findId("Item 2-2-2", myData));<br/>
console.log("Id: ", findId("Wrong Title", myData));<br/>
```

The last one returns `undefined` as intended, since the title is not included in the array.

Comment: It doesn't work well with

Comment: What do you mean? Why? It's working in the snippet, also for the `subs` items.

Comment: console.log("Id: ", findId("Item 2-2-3")) shows undefined

Comment: There is no element with that title. What result would you expect? EDIT  Oh, you update your array... Let me update the one in my post.

Comment: It would be great. Thank you!!

Comment: Updated! It now also supports nested `subs`